# Update value in table based on condition in other table with trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-5.7, phpmyadmin

I have 2 tables, **first** stores the details of all the races [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0pY5.png):[image: Races Details] 
 and **second** the users who have joined which races [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/knKPD.png):[image: Users who have joined which races]

I want to update the **race_status** to **Full** and **record_status** to **2** in **race** table, if **race_id** count in **second** table is **5** per **race_id**. I have created a MySQL trigger for it here is the trigger code for it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `user_race_count` BEFORE INSERT ON `tbl_map_race`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE a1,a2 INT;
    SELECT tbl_map_race.race_id, COUNT(tbl_map_race.race_id) INTO a1,a2
    FROM `tbl_map_race`
    GROUP BY tbl_map_race.race_id;
    IF ((a1 = NEW.race_id) AND (a2>=5))
    THEN 
        UPDATE tbl_race 
        SET tbl_race.race_status = 'Full', tbl_race.record_status = '2' 
        WHERE tbl_race.race_id = @r_id; 
    END IF; 
END
```

In the trigger **tbl_race** is the **first** table and **tbl_map_race** is the **second** table.
Trigger is successfully getting created but when I run query to join the race with trigger working behind I'm not able to update values in **first** table, but if I drop the trigger and run the query I'm able to insert a record in **second** table. Any help to this would be appreciated. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `user_race_count` 
AFTER INSERT 
ON `tbl_map_race`
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    IF 5 <= ( SELECT COUNT( /* DISTINCT */ user_id) 
              FROM tbl_map_race
              WHERE race_id = NEW.race_id)
    THEN 
        UPDATE tbl_race 
        SET race_status = 'Full'
          , record_status = '2' 
        WHERE race_id = NEW.race_id; 
    END IF; 
END
```

Comment: This has solved the case of my problem. Thank you for the quick response.